# How does Leaflet understand parameter 'e' in the Chloropleth tutorial?

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to understand the JS [in this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) popular tutorial.

The essence of the tutorial is this function which passes the parameter `'e'` to the function. 'e''s `target` property is the self-referencing layer of the function.

```
function highlightFeature(e) {
    var layer = e.target;

    layer.setStyle({
        weight: 5,
        color: '#666',
        dashArray: '',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    });

    if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
        layer.bringToFront();
    }
}
```

How does JavaScript understand `'e'`? When the callbacks to the function are made, no parameter is passed to the function as a variable in the event listener.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html ...

> First we’ll define an event listener for layer mouseover event

e is the mouseover event

So the sequence is like that

1. GeoJSON layer finds features and creates layers out of them
2. Each time a layer (e.g. a L.Polygon) is created, you are called back with **onEachFeature**
3. You can attach an event listener to the layer (e.g. mouseover)
4. Later on, when this layer receives a mouseover event, it will send the event (e) back to you

Note: if you need your geojson feature properties by the time your receive a mouseover event from your layer, just keep them in your layer object in **onEachFeature** callback

```
layer.properties = feature.properties;
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FranceImage/ebbgdomu/) where color is defined in the geojson properties

Comment: I see it is a nested object that captures the event. If I want to get a property of layer I am mouseover-ing by pulling up its feature from my geojson file, how can I do that? Does that make sense?